# Ansible to reconnect after reboot

Tags: ansible

I have a task that needs to run after a reboot. I know that checking connection can be done with `wait_for_connection`.

I have the following draft:

```
- name: Reboot host
  reboot:

- name: Wait 300 seconds, but only start checking after 60 seconds
  wait_for_connection:
    delay: 60
    timeout: 300

- name: Do some other stuff
  .
  ..
```

...

Does the `wait_for_connection` module automatically reconnects once available? Or do I have to have a seperate task for that? Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1):

as per reboot module [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/reboot_module.html) it does what you want out of the box:

```
 Synopsis
 - Reboot a machine, wait for it to go down, come back up, and respond to commands.
 ...
```

So you do not have to manage it with a separate task!

If server you try to reboot is very slow you can increase the timout of module to wait server go back on-line correctly.

So any task you need to run after a reboot the only think you have to do is insert it after the task reboot the machine.